# how to enter characters one by one in to a text field in selenium webdriver with node js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm searching a way where I can keep typing in a message box and switch to another window to verify isTyping...appears
can anybody suggest a way to achieve this?
Note: isTyping...appears only when other user is actively types

I tried to use Sendkeys() but by the time I switch the window isTyping... disappears

Comment: If you need to have two windows being tested in parallel you need 2 webdriver instances